# Does the series $ \sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{f(n)}\log^{(i)}(n)} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

By integral comparison it is fairly easy to prove that the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq N_k}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^k\log^{(i)}(n)}
$$
diverges for all integers $k\geq 0$, where for an integer $i\geq 1$
$$
\log^{(i)}(n):=\underbrace{\log(...\log(}_{i\text{ times}}n)...)
$$
and $\log^{(0)}(n):=n$, and where $N_k$ is sufficiently large such that all terms of the sum are properly defined.

Now I wonder: if we define
$$
f(n):=\max\{i\in\mathbb{N}_0:\log^{(i)}(n)> 1\},
$$
then does the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{f(n)}\log^{(i)}(n)}
$$
converge? And if so, how about the bigger series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{f(n)+1}\log^{(i)}(n)}
$$
?

Edit: and what about the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{f(n)+2}\log^{(i)}(n)};
$$
is it conditionally convergent, or perhaps even absolutely convergent?

Comment: Also, the third series is conditionally convergent iff it's absolutely convergent, since every term is $\lt 0$; by your definition, $0\lt \log^{(f(n)+1)}(n)\lt 1$ and so $\log^{(f(n)+2)}(n)\lt 0$ for all $n$. (With one very small subtle catch being that I don't think it's actually known that you can't have a zero denominator, even though everyone believes it to be true)

Comment: I believe it's known that the first series diverges, and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111244/series-with-iterated-logs-does-it-converge suggests that it's a Putnam problem.